# File / Image storage with access via .Net

Tags: c#, .net, storage

I have a Virtual Private Server running windows IIS hosing a startup site (.net sql),  it has limited hard drive space. Id like to store image files via a service and not on my VPS.

Google reveals lots of consumer based services but they don't have an API.

Im wondering if anyone knows of a storage service that I can save files or images using .Net code?

**EDIT**: looking for a free service initially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/) are two obvious options. Most cloud based solutions should offer this.

Try [this](http://www.freecloudstorageproviders.net/) for potential freebies. I don't know enough about your requirements to know whether any of them fit the bill or not.

Comment: Sorry,I forgot to mention, id like it to be free

Comment: I think you're out of luck on the free part. Also Amazon S3 is not a CDN. If using that use CloudFront which is a CDN on top of Amazon S3.

Comment: Thanks Simon, thanks Asken...Cloudfront with S3 is what im going for. If you make this an answer I will mark it as such